# Unintentionally "Dismissing Current View" on iOS 17.1.2 in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, dismiss, ios17

When trying to open a URL using

```
Link(destination: URL(string: terms_url)!) { Text("Terms") }`
```

the current view unintentionally dismissed to parent view in `iOS 17.1.2` SwiftUI. It only occurs in this newest version (as of Dec 9, 2023) of iOS. This bug also appears when running these lines of code:

```
let product: SKProduct = ...//Selected subscription here
let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
```

I use the environment variable `@Environment(\.dismiss)` to dismiss the view in question. But I assure that this issue is not caused by that.

Comment: The code you show is not enough to solve the isssue. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Actually it is all clear. This seems to be a bug. Any URL I open using Button, Link etc. cause dismissal of current view. App opens the link successfully, but just after directing to the link, view dismisses itself, although I don’t intent.